# Где можно посмотреть все функции вектора прерываний 0х80?

Tags: linux, системное-программирование

Есть ли где-то документация по прерываниям из 80h Linux? Как узнать, например, какие аргументы принимает та или иная функция? (например, 4 принимает дескриптор файла, куда писать и длину данных, но в каком файле это записано?). Хочу посмотреть все функции вектора прерываний с аргументами.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Comment: @eanmos Мне нужен именно файл в системе Linux ubuntu. Знаю, что есть два отдельных файла для х86 и x64 систем.

Comment: В каждой системе по-разному. Смотрите в `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`. Там будет несколько инклюдов, которые содержат системные вызовы для вашей платформы. Для моей платформы − x86_64 − это `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`

Comment: https://www.informatik.htw-dresden.de/~beck/ASM/syscall_list.html